# C Compilation error in Make but not GCC/G++

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I've just started experimenting with C, but am having issues compiling a simple, single file application from the command line with Make (on Ubuntu 14.04.2). I've included math.h, but methods like `ceil` and `sqrt` are 'undefined' when using Make. It seems Make can't link the math.h library, but GCC/G++ seems to do just fine. What's going on here?

The C code is in a sample-fail.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

double sqrt(double x);
double ceil(double x);

//Checks if an array contains any values that evenly divide 'val'
int array_contains_divisor(int arr[], int len, int val)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(val % arr[i] == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

//Finds the largest prime factor of 'value'. Returns -1 if the number is
//prime, 0 if invalid
int largest_prime_factor(long value)
{
    //1 and 0 are not prime, this function does not expect negatives
    //so anything less than 1 is an invalid value
    if( value <= 1L )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    double val = (double)value;

    double d_max = ceil( sqrt( val ) );

    if( d_max > INT_MAX )
    {
        //value is invalid because its square root exceeds the maximum 
        //capacity of an int (defined in limits.h)
        return 0;
    }

    int max = (int)d_max;

    int prime_len = (int)( d_max / 2 ) + 1;

    int primes[prime_len];

    int primes_curr_pos = 0;

    int i;

    for(i = 9; i < max; i+=2)
    {
        //check if it's a factor
        if( value % i != 0 )
        {
            continue;
        }

        //basic prime check - should be no need to check 2 because we
        //are skipping all the even numbers
        if( i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 == 0 )
        {
            continue;
        }

        //complete prime check (not including 2, 3, 5 and 7)
        if( array_contains_divisor( primes, primes_curr_pos, i ) )
        {
            continue;
        }

        primes[primes_curr_pos++] = i;
    }

    //if we've found no prime divisors, check the remaining primes
    //we skipped earlier.
    if( primes_curr_pos <= 0 )
    {
        if( value % 7 == 0)
        {
            primes[primes_curr_pos++] = 7;
        }
        else if( value % 5 == 0 )
        {
            primes[primes_curr_pos++] = 5;
        }
        else if( value % 3 == 0 )
        {
            primes[primes_curr_pos++] = 3;
        }
        else if( value % 2 == 0 )
        {
            primes[primes_curr_pos++] = 3;
        }
    }

    if( primes_curr_pos <= 0 )
    {
        //the value is prime, return -1;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return primes[primes_curr_pos - 1];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("The largest prime factor of 600851475143 is %d\n", 
        largest_prime_factor(600851475143));

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Terminal output from trying to compile sample_fail.c with Make, and then with GCC/G++ (I just copied the steps I saw the Code::Blocks builder take for the GCC/G++ commands):

```
x@x-desktop:~/Documents/Random Scripts$ ./sample_fail
bash: ./sample_fail: No such file or directory
x@x-desktop:~/Documents/Random Scripts$ make sample_fail
cc     sample_fail.c   -o sample_fail
/tmp/ccGCCT0E.o: In function `largest_prime_factor':
sample_fail.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `sqrt'
sample_fail.c:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `ceil'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sample_fail] Error 1
x@x-desktop:~/Documents/Random Scripts$ gcc -Wall -c sample_fail.c
x@x-desktop:~/Documents/Random Scripts$ g++ -o ./sample_fail ./sample_fail.o
x@x-desktop:~/Documents/Random Scripts$ ./sample_fail
The largest prime factor of 600851475143 is 6857
x@x-desktop:~/Documents/Random Scripts$
```

Thanks in advance for any help for this C newbie.

Solution (courtesy of user3629249 and Useless):

Updated my Makefile to read:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
CC=gcc

sample_fail: sample_fail.c
    gcc -o sample_fail sample_fail.c -lm

clean:
    rm -f sample_fail
```

make sample_fail now works on the Terminal.

Comment: gcc  seems to automatically link m, your cc doesn't. What does the makefile say?

Comment: Looks like make is invoking `cc` instead of `gcc`. Try setting `CC=gcc` in your Makefile, so both versions use the same compiler.

Comment: It looks like `g++` is linking libm. Can you try using `gcc` instead of `g++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the link step of the compile/link sequence needs to be told '-lm' (lower case 'L') when

```
#include <math.h>
```

is in the source code.

note ceil() and sqrt() prototypes are defined in math.h so should not have those prototypes overridden in the source code.

Comment: -lm corrects the error, thank you. The following GCC command works: x@tx-desktop:~/Documents/Random Scripts$ gcc -Wall -o sample_fail sample_fail.c -lm